# how to use values of 2 different tables in asp.net with eval from database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, eval

Hi I want to put name of the city instead of id of the city

in my data base I have id of city in my table1 and i have another table that Included id and name of the city

now I can use this code

```
<h5 class="urun-fiyat"><%# Eval("cityid")%></h5>
```

to see the id of the city but i need name of the city

i dont have city name in table1 and i should take it with inner join or some other way from table2

what should i do ?!

Comment: Use a view instead of table. In view you can join with the table which includes name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general (and easy) approach?

Build a query that pulls in the "text" City value based on the city_id.

In most cases, I suggest createing a view.

So, say we have this:

```
SELECT People.FirstName, People.LastName, People.Hotel_ID
FROM People
```

that gives this:

| FirstName | LastName | Hotel_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | Smith | 77 |
| Bob | Phoenix | 102 |
| Correy | Lollas | 102 |
| Ronz | Howerd | 102 |
| Scott | Stevens | 77 |
| Marianne | Tucker | 77 |
| Bob | Hamilton | 77 |
| Super | Man | 77 |
| John | Smith | 82 |
| Princes | Leia | 77 |
| Joe | Blow | NULL |
| Luke | Skywalker | 77 |
| Hans | Solo | 102 |
| Darth | Vader | 102 |
| Albert | Kallal | 82 |

As you can see, the Hotel_ID is not much use.

So, in the query builder, then we build a left join, say like this:

[image]

So, now, we "look up" by using a simple left join, and we now have the Hotel Name as a text value from the other table.

So, sql becomes this:

```
SELECT People.Firstname, People.LastName, People.Hotel_ID, tblHotels.HotelName
FROM People 
LEFT JOIN tblHotels ON People.Hotel_ID = tblHotels.ID
```

And now output becomes this:

| Firstname | LastName | Hotel_ID | HotelName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | Smith | 77 | Jasper Park Lodge |
| Bob | Phoenix | 102 | Big White Resort |
| Correy | Lollas | 102 | Big White Resort |
| Ronz | Howerd | 102 | Big White Resort |
| Scott | Stevens | 77 | Jasper Park Lodge |
| Marianne | Tucker | 77 | Jasper Park Lodge |
| Bob | Hamilton | 77 | Jasper Park Lodge |
| Super | Man | 77 | Jasper Park Lodge |
| John | Smith | 82 | Canadian Rocky Mountain Resorts |
| Princes | Leia | 77 | Jasper Park Lodge |
| Joe | Blow | NULL | NULL |
| Luke | Skywalker | 77 | Jasper Park Lodge |
| Hans | Solo | 102 | Big White Resort |
| Darth | Vader | 102 | Big White Resort |
| Albert | Kallal | 82 | Canadian Rocky Mountain Resorts |

So, do what is called a left join. I suggest a "left" join, since some of the Hotel_ID values may not exist, and we don't have a hotel_id, but we still want to include the row in the grid.